# preg_match work at online tester but not at my server

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to get `NAME HERE` of `REALIB_PF_D1 NAME HERE PEDRO ANTONIO DE SOUZA`

```
$data = "REALIB_PF_D1 NAME HERE PEDRO ANTONIO DE SOUZA";
$name = array();
if (preg_match("/REALIB_PF_D1(.*?)PEDRO ANTONIO DE SOUZA/U", $data, $name)) {
    var_dump($name);
}
```

But `$name` still empty.

I have tested in https://www.phpliveregex.com/ and works correctly.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Works for me. May be you have hidden characters somewhere.